# Is there an analog of Emotions 'css' function in MUI 5?

Tags: css, material-ui, emotion, css-in-js

As I understand MUI 5 uses Emotion under the hood for styling, Emotion has this nice helper function `css` that looks like returns a string - a class name that you could use as a value for `className` or *any other* property.

```
import { css, cx } from '@emotion/css'

render(
  <div
    className={css`
      padding: 32px;
      background-color: hotpink;
      font-size: 24px;
    `}
  >
    Text
  </div>
)
```

I looked everywhere but could not find an analog available in MUI. There is `css` function in system and styled-engine but it does not seem to do the same, it returns `SerializedStyles`.

The use case I am looking to use it for is following:

I have a component that let's you to pass class-names (strings) for different parts of that component enabling you to change the component's styling. It seems like this `css` function (as shown in Emotion docs) could help me with this.

e.g.:

```js
const headerStyle = css`
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
`;

<Component
  headerClassName={headerStyle}
  footerClassName={css`
    color: gray;
    font-size: 2rem;
  `}
/>
```

I guess I could solve it with `makeStyles()` but it is "legacy" not and the syntax shown on the screenshot above is more compelling to me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use Emotion's `css` function?

Comment: If you mean "css function directly from @emotion/css" - I'd like to avoid extra dependencies (in order it to work I need to add it to package.json), given that MUI is already using Emotion I would expect it could be possible to access it (or MUI wrapper for it) somehow through the MUI, but I do not see a way so far and that's what the question is about...

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you mean by avoiding extra dependencies. MUI expects you to install emotion (listed as [peer dependencies](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b208789c8b5d659c984c44a323ac8fc27a2c8d98/packages/mui-styled-engine/package.json#L46-L47)) if you want to use the default style-engine. Without [installing](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm) a styling library, You can't use the MUI styling API like `sx` or `styled`.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, It looks like In order the desired `css` function to be available I need to explicitly install `@emotion/css`, it is not required by the styled-engine. The styled-engine requires `@emotion/react` which does have `css` function but it appears to be _different_ function, which is actually quite confusing.

Comment: Yeah my bad, so `css` returns different things when importing from `@emotion/react` or `@emotion/css`. It looks like MUI v5 styling API does not expose the resulted class name anymore unless you use the old `makeStyles` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper of your `Component` and inject the style down from the parent component like below:

```
<Box sx={{
  '& .myHeader': {
    // your header styles
  },
  '& .myFooter': {
    // your footer styles
  },
}}>
  <Component
    headerClassName='myHeader'
    footerClassName='myFooter'
  />
</Box>
```

Or using `styled`:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const headerClass = "header";
const footerClass = "footer";

const Container = styled("div")`
  & .${headerClass} {
    background-color: red;
  }
  & .${footerClass} {
    background-color: blue;
  }
`;

function Component({ headerClassName, footerClassName }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={headerClassName}>h</div>
      <div className={footerClassName}>f</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
<Container>
  <Component headerClassName={headerClass} footerClassName={footerClass} />
</Container>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Near! While this should do the work, this is not exactly the approach I would be happy with, the reasons are 1) Necessity to repeat names twice as string (not type/symbol safe way) as opposed to assigning style to a constant which would be better for refactoring down the line. 2) This still uses object-style of writing css which is not something I'd like to do, string-style (as shown above) is more preferable way.

Comment: @Paul see my updated answer. A bit better I suppose?

Comment: I might be in the same situation as Paul and in this case @NearHuscarl's solution isn't exactly tackling this specific use case: for instance, when using the same CSS definitions on several different element types, such as different SVG elements, where the as= property becomes a nightmare. In such situations n=cx(css(...)) would give access to the CSS class name and simplify things with className.

Comment: When using `css` from `@mui/system` the returned object contains a `name` field. Can this be used as a CSS class name?

Comment: @TheDiveO theoretically yes, by concating the cache prefix `css-`, but I'm not sure if you should do that because emotion does some magic under the hood besides simply adding the class name

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ClassNames } from '@emotion/react';

export const Component = ({ className, sx, ...rest }) => (
  <ClassNames>
    {({ css, cx }) => (
      <div className={cx(className, css(sx))} {...rest} /> 
    )}
  </ClassNames>
);
```

use like that:

```
<Component sx={{ color: "green" }} className="someClass">text</Component>
```

also you can wrap className to css():

```
<div className={cx(css(className), css(sx))} {...rest} />
```